# MySql procedure insert if foreign key not exist

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement, equals

first of all my english is not so good but i think maybe enogh. Ok, I have a procedure for inserting.

Procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `PhotoUpdate`(IN `uid` INT, IN `foto` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO photos (Dosya, UyeID)
    VALUES (foto, uid)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UyeID = uid;
END
```

And Im calling it like this

```
Call PhotoUpdate(87,'87_54284.jpg');
```

Photos table is
<kbd>**id**</kbd>     <kbd>Dosya</kbd>                  <kbd>UyeID</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>55_48615.jpg</kbd>      <kbd>55</kbd>      
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>87_95165.jpg</kbd>      <kbd>87</kbd>

Im trying to ('uid'->87) if uid equals to photos.UyeID, I mean if UyeID=87 then Update row. If else then insert.

---

This querys that i tryd. But didnt work.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM photos WHERE UyeID = uid)
  UPDATE photos SET Dosya = foto WHERE UyeID = uid;
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO photos (Dosya, UyeID) Values(foto, uid);
END IF;
```

How can i do this guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `PhotoUpdate`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `PhotoUpdate`(`uid` INT UNSIGNED, `foto` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `photos` (`Dosya`, `UyeID`)
    VALUES (`foto`, `uid`)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Dosya` = `foto`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/503c1/1)</kbd>

Comment: You use indentifiers in the values

Comment: @Gervs: The values ​​are the parameters. See demo.

Comment: @Gervs: Please, moderate your language in your comments. See the documentation: [9.2 Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: I see no reason why I should change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try REPLACE INTO photos (Dosya, UyeID) VALUES(foto, uid);

Answer (score 0):

If you create an unique index on UyeID, or even better get rid of the ID column and make UyeID the primary key, you can use INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Example

```
INSERT INTO photos (Dosya, UyeID)
VALUES ('example.jpg', 87)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Dosya = VALUES(Dosya)
```

If you use VALUES you can use this also with a bulk insert